# Why scroll metric is different in IE when compared to other browsers? Is there any proper fix?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

**There is little problem in IE, is there any perfect fix/solution?**

Looking for solution that uses below CSS property on child div's

```
display: inline-block;
```

When a parent `div` has 2 child div's

- Second child `div` is given pre-defined `width`
- First child `div` `width` is calculated dynamically based on available width.

When child div has CSS properties as given in below snippets, there is wired behavior for parent div scroll metrics in IE. `scrollHeight` it varies by few pixels in IE when compared to other browsers like Chrome, Firefox, Edge.

Is there any proper solution to position child divs with out any side effects when displayed `inline-block` and have content `overflow` hidden.

```js
  function metrics() {
    var parent = document.querySelector("#parent");
    var parentMetrics = document.querySelector("#parentMetrics");

    parentMetrics.innerText = 'Parent Scroll Height: ' + parent.scrollHeight + '\n' + 'Parent Client Height: ' + parent.clientHeight + '\n' + 'Parent Offset Height: ' + parent.offsetHeight;
  }
metrics();
```

```css
#parent {
  background-color: orange;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#firstChildDiv {
  background-color: brown;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#secondChildDiv {
  background-color: skyblue;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="firstChildDiv">FIRST CHILD: Please RUN this snippet in IE, there is scroll problem in IE,  other browsers like, Chrome, Firefox, Edge behave properly.
  </div><!--
FIX FOR WHITE SPACE
  --><div id="secondChildDiv">
    SECOND CHILD
  </div>
</div>


<div id="parentMetrics">

</div>
```

```js
  function metrics() {
    var parent = document.querySelector("#parent");
    var parentMetrics = document.querySelector("#parentMetrics");

    parentMetrics.innerText = 'Parent Scroll Height: ' + parent.scrollHeight + '\n' + 'Parent Client Height: ' + parent.clientHeight + '\n' + 'Parent Offset Height: ' + parent.offsetHeight;
  }
metrics();
```

```css
#parent {
  background-color: orange;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size:0;
}

#firstChildDiv {
  font-size:14px;
  background-color: brown;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#secondChildDiv {
  font-size:14px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="firstChildDiv">FIRST CHILD: Please RUN this snippet in IE, there is scroll problem in IE,  other browsers like, Chrome, Firefox, Edge behave properly.
  </div>
  <div id="secondChildDiv">
    SECOND CHILD
  </div>
</div>


<div id="parentMetrics">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just because of default browser styles. To normalize, you could attack `line-height` this way:

```
#parent {
    line-height: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

below CSS fix solves unnecessary scrollHeight problem that is in IE

- **parent and both children**  elements are given same **pre-defined** `height`
- `vertical-allign: middle;`

```js
  function metrics() {
    var parent = document.querySelector("#parent");
    var parentMetrics = document.querySelector("#parentMetrics");

    parentMetrics.innerHTML = '<hr>Parent Scroll Height: <span>' + parent.scrollHeight + '</span><hr>' + 'Parent Client Height: <span>' + parent.clientHeight +'</span><hr>';
  }
metrics();
```

```css
#parent {
  background-color: orange;
  font-size: 0;
  height:100px;
}

#firstChildDiv {
  background-color: brown;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height:100px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#secondChildDiv {
  background-color: skyblue;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height:100px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#parentMetrics{
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  padding:10px;
}
span{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="firstChildDiv">FIRST CHILD: Test in IE to see the difference.
  </div>
  <div id="secondChildDiv">
    SECOND CHILD
  </div>
</div>


<div id="parentMetrics">
</div>
```